# How to populate associative array through for loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I need to create this kind of element inside my array:

```
{ Field1: "2011/04/23", Field2: 8, Field3: "Adam", Field4: "Den"},  
{ Field1: "2011/03/25", Field2: 6, Field3: "Honey",Field4: "Singh"}
```

How may I increasce that field`1` counter ?

```
var resultado = [];
    for(i=0;  i< dados.length; i++){                
        resultado[i] = { "Field"+i: dados[columns[i]]};
    }
```

If I try to do like above, it gives me an error saying I can't use the `+` character.  How may I achieve my goal ?

Obs: i'll not always have 4 fields, it may vary.

**UPDATE**

Following the answers I could achieve part of what I need, now the code is like this:

```
var resultado = [];
    for(i=0;  i< dados.length; i++){                
        resultado[i] = { ["Field"+i]: dados[columns[i]]};
    }
```

But I'm not managing to write all of that in a single position of the array.
How may I get this:

```
var results = [
      {
       Field1: "2011/04/23",
       Field2: 8,
       Field3: "Adam",
       Field4: "Den"  
      }, //First Element  

      {
       Field1: "2011/03/25",
       Field2: 6,
       Field3: "Honey",
       Field4: "Singh"  
      } //Second Element
    ];
```

I'm using JqueryDataTable, so I need to create an obj to populate it dinamically.

I have an ajax that returns me a Json with the `name of the columns`.

```
["id_localidade","cod_munic","id_bairro","id_endereco"]  
//These are column names that I need to use later.
```

Then I have another Ajax to bring me the DATA from this same table as a Json:

```
[  
{"id_bairro":"1","dsc_bairro":"PONTE DOS CARVALHOS"},  
{"id_bairro":"2","dsc_bairro":"CHARNECA"},  
{"id_bairro":"3","dsc_bairro":"SAO FRANCISCO"},  
{"id_bairro":"4","dsc_bairro":"ROSARIO"}  
]
```

So now I need to use these two arrays and create the this:

```
{ Field1: "2011/04/23", Field2: 8, Field3: "Adam", Field4: "Den"},
```

Where Field1, Field2, FieldN will depend on how many columns the selected column has. (As I have the name of those columns I just need to count it).

What I tried so far (without success):

```
var nFields   = Object.keys(dados[0]).length;//Number of columns
var nElements = dados.length; //Number of registers

var resultado = [];
for(i=1;  i<= nElements; i++){
   for(j=0; j < nFields; j++){
      var temp = [];
      temp.push({ ["Field"+ (j+1)]: dados[j][ columns[j]['sTitle'] ] });
      resultado = temp;
   }                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brackets to produce a computed name for a property of an object.

> Obs: i'll not always have 4 fields, it may vary.

If `dados` array is an array of arrays, utilize nested `for` loop to iterate each element of current `dados[i]` array.

```js
var dados = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8]
];
var resultado = [];
var prop = "Field";
for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
  resultado[i] = {};
  for (var n = 1; n < dados[i].length; n++) {
    resultado[i][prop + n] = dados[i][n - 1];
  }
}

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: And how may I create all of those:  `Field1: "", Field2: ""`. I'm having dificult to insert all of the necessary fields in a single row of the object dinamically

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Have you tried stacksnippets? Created example `dados` array of arrays which have variable `.length`. At inner `for` loop iterate each element of inner array. The property name of the object should be incremented beginning at `"Field1"`, where `n` at inner loop is initially set to `1`. Note the `n-1` within bracket at `dados[i][n - 1]`. Which portion of `javascript` at Answer are you experiencing difficulties utilizing?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Is `dados` the array of objects?

Comment: Worked what you said. I just took a better look and it's running like a boss.  I'll post the answer aswell.

Answer (score 1):

> Just as a note - in javascript they are not called associative arrays, they are just objects.

## option1:

You can create an empty object, and then add the key using `obj[key]`:

```
var resultado = [];
for(i=0;  i< dados.length; i++){                
    resultado[i] = {};
    resultado[i]["Field"+i] = dados[columns[i]]
}
```

## option2:

You can create the name of the key before using it:

```
var resultado = [];
for(i=0;  i< dados.length; i++){                
    key = "Field"+i
    resultado[i] = {key: dados[columns[i]]};
}
```

Comment: And how may I create all of those:  `Field1: "", Field2: ""`. I'm having dificult to insert all of the necessary fields in a single row of the object dinamically

Comment: A bit hard to help because I don't know the content of `columns` and `dados`. Add them to the question

Answer (score 1):

You could use a default object, if `resultado[i]` is not set and use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for the access.

```
resultado[i] = resultado[i] || {};
resultado[i]["Field" + i] = dados[columns[i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `push` method.

```
var resultado = [];
for(var i=0;  i< dados.length; i++){                
    resultado.push({ "Field"+i : dados[columns[i]]});
}
```

Comment: There is no just `var` improvement. See it again.

Comment: Thanks man. But I already tried that  I just changed to see if for some miracle reason it would work this way.